# Make the copy progress dialog always on top

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz

I want to make the copy dialogue to be "always on top". I have the command

```
wmctrl -r "window title" -b add,above
```

All I have to do now is to monitor any windows that opens up. How can I do this? Or is there any other approach to accomplish the task?

Comment: So essentially what you're asking is " If copy dialog exists, set it to be on top of other windows" Correct ?

Comment: @Serg Yes exactly, but not checking (polling) it repeatedly. Anyway that I can just fit the above command in the execution code of the copy dialog so that when it starts it executes the above command as well.

Comment: sorry, but  when you say "automatically" it implies polling.  We need to continuously check if window with the title you want exists.  As for copy dialog itself , you can't just "fit the above command" there. That dialog that used by file manager is written in C, while your command is shell script - it's apple and oranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with CCSM or Compizconfig-settings-manager.

Install it with this command.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it and enable **Window Rules** plugin under **Window Management** section. Go to it's settings, On the **Matches** tab, There will options for settings various types of rule for windows.

Use the option `Above` there. You have to add the window type to it. Then the windows of that class will always be above others.

For the dialog window, you need to add `type=Dialog` in the above field. Like this

[image: above settings]

You can even use the **+** button to grab window class or type. Click on the icon, on the new window, Click on <kbd>Grab</kbd> button. The pointer will now become a crosshair icon. Click on the window you want to set rule for.

[image: grab window]

Experiment with the class and types to find your exact match.

Comment: Worked with "name=file_progress" Thank you!!

Comment: I was wondering if there is any plugin to set the default opacity as well at per app basis?

Comment: @HemantYadav If you have another question, You might ask another question :)

Comment: Never-mind I figured it out, there was "Opacity, Brightness and Saturation" plugin with Window specific settings :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using standard Ubuntu with Unity desktop (not sure about other desktop environments, might be similar), simply right-click on any window's title bar (this also works for dialog windows like the copy progress  dialog) and enable **Always on top**.

[image]

Comment: I Don't want to do it manually, I want it to be "Always on Top" ALWAYS without me clicking it and changing the setting